# DNS zone file for subdomain, query returns host not found 5(REFUSED)

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration, subdomain, domain-name, dns-zone

I'm trying to setup subdomains on my DNS server running Yadifa 1.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit but can't get it to work.

in my yadifad.conf, my zone looks like this

```
<zone>
  type                    master
  domain                  domain.tld.
  file                    masters/domain.tld.zone
  allow-transfer          any                          # for tests
</zone>
```

masters/domain.tld.zone

```
$ORIGIN domain.tld.
domain.tld.              IN    SOA ns.domain.tld. hostmaster.domain.tld. 1 10800 3600 604800 86400
                               A 10.0.0.12
                               NS ns.domain.tld.

ns                       IN    A 10.0.0.250
host                     IN    A 10.0.0.32
host.subdomain           IN    A 10.0.0.110
alias.subdomain          IN    CNAME host.subdomain
```

Running this configuration I can query my server for host.domain.tld fine but if I query for host.subdomain.domain.tld or alias.subdomain.domain.tld I get a `host not found: 5(REFUSED)` error.

I've tried many different configurations like moving my subdomain to it's own zone file but nothing has worked so far.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this software, but I notice you have allow-transfer set. Is there an allow-query too? Can you share your entire config file?

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman you can see a default config file here http://git.io/_e4R1A my config file is basically the same but with my zone block instead of the somedomain.eu zone; so allow_query any

Comment: `allow-transfer` wouldn't have consequences of pure DNS queries... but at the same time you are not showing exactly what queries you do, which commands and which results without paraphrasing. It is most probably you are not even hitting the proper nameserver. But as you (badly) obfuscated erverything, noone can really help you.

Comment: "you can see a default config file here git.io/_e4R1A"  Don't do that. When you post a question, post the relevant part of all needed logfiles as text in the question itself. Links can go stale, be restricted in access, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that YADIFA is installed in `/usr/local` ?

If it's the same configuration file with only the zone edited then go in your configuration file folder and do:

```
sed -i 's/local-dev/local/g' yadifad.conf
```